# If I help "evacuate" a building, what am I doing to the people?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

I remember reading somewhere that to evacuate a person is a medical procedure, and not something to be done during an earthquake. (I thought it was in Fowler, but I just looked and couldn't see it). The point is that it is the *building* that is being evacuated, not the people. "Evacuate" comes from the Latin word for "to  empty out".

If this is so, what is happening to the people that are being helped out of a building that is being evacuated?

I was reminded of this question during an episode of CSI: Miami (don't judge me) where someone tells flame-haired Horatio Caine that "You helped evacuate me yesterday". What *should* she have said to him? "You helped evacuate the building I was in" sounds a little circumlocutionary.

I should have anticipated answers saying "You can use evacuate like that". As far as I can tell, the [OED](http://oed.com/view/Entry/65161) doesn't allow "evacuate" to be the verb that you do to people when removing them from a burning building. So there isn't quite a consensus that I'm barking up the wrong tree, although the concise OED allows "to remove from a place of danger".

Let's say I didn't want to do that for the (perhaps mistaken) reason that it was worth having a distinction between what is being made empty and what it is being emptied *of*. Let's say I'm super-worried about there being some confusion about whether Horatio helped the woman get to the hurricane shelter or whether he helped perform an unlicensed medical procedure on her. Both might be legitimate readings of "He helped her evacuate". I want this to refer to the latter, so how would I unambiguously talk about the former?

Comment: You're *evacuating* them.

Comment: Do you want synonyms for *evacuate*?  If that's the case most of your question is now peeving against what is actually correct use of the word.

Comment: @z7sg I'm looking for synonyms of _one meaning_ of evacuate, I guess. I don't want synonyms of evacuate as in "I helped evacuate the building". I'm dreadfully sorry that I tried to do more than just post "I CAN HAZ SYNONYM". Whether or not it's correct usage, there is some ambiguity (in fairly rarified circumstances, granted). So I don't think it's "peeving"

Comment: It is peeving because you keep saying they *shouldn't* say it, or that evacuate means "to make empty".  That's wrong.  Evacuate means: (1) "remove (someone) from a place of danger to a safer place" (2) "remove air, water, or other contents from (a container)"

Comment: @z7sg That depends on your sources. Also I don't think one "should" counts as "I keep saying should"... Read it as "What should she have said..." (if she was interested in making clear she was referring to the evacuation of a building, not to her most recent bowel movement. Both of which Horatio might have helped with.

Comment: @Seamus: I have to say I think the basic premise of the question is a bit odd. There's general agreement that *evacuate* is a perfectly valid verb which fits your context better than any alternative. You seem to be asking for the nearest equivalent to that "best fit" word, but I can't really see why. We don't avoid using the word *movement*, for example, just in case someone thinks we're talking about bowel movements rather than part of a symphony.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, that last part made me laugh! lol

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't think there's as much agreement as all that. First, the OED online doesn't make it clear it can be used like that, second there was this thing I vaguely remember reading complaining about exactly that usage. Let's say I wanted a synoynm because I was worried about the ambiguity. I might also be worried about the ambiguity of _movement_ but that's another question. Does its being an odd request make it an invalid question? (Someone who downvoted obviously thought so).

Comment: It will perhaps be interesting to know that *evacuo* was not a word at all in the Latin of the Golden Age, nor in that of the Republic. Cicero would have balked at it. At any rate, he would have disapproved of most of the ways we mutilate Latin. And if one thinks of the sordid origins of the Germanic languages, one loses all pride whatsoever. So I say each case should be judged on its own: whether ancestor of a certain word was used thus or so in Latin is only one of the several arguments we have to determine proper style.

Comment: @Seamus: the OED does clearly support this usage — it just lists so many earlier meanings first that you have to read on for a while.  But its senses 8a and 8b are “To clear out, remove (inhabitants, inmates, or troops)”, and “To remove (inhabitants of an area liable to aerial bombing or other hazards) to safer surroundings”, with examples like “Mr. Greenwood and others strongly appealed to the Prime Minister to evacuate children at once.”

Comment: Actually you evacuate the building not the people.  If you are a fireman or rescue worker you extract people from the building.  Helping to evacuate could mean as pulling a fire alarm and getting out to helping to extract people.  It could also mean you lead a group out through the escape route.  It is used vaguely there so that the focus would be on helping rather than the actual action performed.

Comment: @PLL You're right. Serves me right for not carefully reading all the definitions.

Comment: @Chad: In light of PPL's comment and example above, I see no justification for your comment. The meaning and usage of words *does* change, and this clearly applies to "evacuate" here. Appeals to historical usage are irrelevant.

Comment: @FumbleFingers My comment about wanting a synoynm to avoid confusion is still justified. Historical usage of words is hardly irrelevant since that is, in large part, the determinant of current usage. In this case, it's true that modern usage _has_ changed, but to claim that historical usage is irrelevant seems overkill.

Comment: @Seamus: The word "irrelevant" was directed at Chad's denial of the shift in meaning. My position on the merits of the question itself are in my first comment above (I also upvoted z7sg Ѫ's comment because I largely agree with that as well).

Comment: @Fumblefingers  I was not trying to imply that the way it is being used is wrong just how it should be interpreted.  Even in the current usage the when we say "someone was evacuated" it has an implied or often explict "From somewhere."  Using it with out that context would imply that the person was emptied (or at least some portion of them).

Comment: @Chad: This is going nowhere. You said *"Actually you evacuate the building not the people"*. PPL showed that people *can* be evacuated in a non-medical context. No amount of caveats can justify you denying that the very usage we are speaking of here is in fact valid.

Comment: @Fumblefingers - I acknowledge that it could be taken that way.  But that was not my intent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd say that you are [rescuing](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/rescue) them, or helping them [exit](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/exit) the building.

Answer (score 14):

e·vac·u·ate

1. Remove (someone) from a place of danger to a safe place.
2. Leave or cause the occupants to leave (a place of danger).

Evacuate is the correct word here.

Comment: See edit: let's say I don't want to use evacuate.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some rough (and in some cases rather arguable) synonyms of *evacuate*

- abandon
- desert
- withdraw
- move out

They do not bear the same meaning as *evacuate*, but it is possible to use them instead of evacuate. You just need to explicitly describe the situation.

*Sailors abandoned ship the moment it become obvious they can't save her.*

Comment: Horatio did none of these things to the poor woman in the question. Well, maybe he helped her withdraw, but that seems a stretch... None has the connotation of evacuate.

Comment: Well, he helped her to abandon the building, didn't he? I told the synonyms are arguable :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the *to make empty* definition, several dictionaries also list *to remove (persons or things) from a place, as a dangerous place or disaster area, for reasons of safety or protection: to evacuate the inhabitants of towns in the path of a flood.*

So *evacuate* works in either case.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your narrower use of *evacuate*. (I thought there was a reference in either *Strunk & White* or *Chicago Manual of Style*, but I have not found it. Something about firemen and children and a school.)

You are being careful, rather than circumloquacious with either

> "You helped evacuate the building in which I lay unconscious."

or

> "You helped evacuate my stomach when I had ingested an excess of hallucinogens."

However, these are not the kind of sentences that either most CSI fans could parse or the CBS writers would write.

(I can just imagine the camera lingering on Horatio as he takes two beats, puts on his sunglasses, and stands three-quarters to the camera with his arms akimbo. "Miss Winworth, it was my privilege to do so.")

Comment: What is the edition and page number where the use of *evacuate* is prescribed?

Comment: It is not in 4th ed., 3rd ed., or the 1918 original. I have one more to check when I get home.

Comment: I had a quick look in Strunk & White, but it wasn't in the index so I gave up...

Comment: I looked under "misused words," but could not find it. I can file this under "misattributed to Elements of Style." I'm editing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, it is completely correct to say, "You evacuated me from the building." I just checked two dictionaries and both list "to withdraw inhabitants from a threatened area" (with slightly different wording) as one of the definitions.

So when the questioner says that this usage is incorrect and the person should have used different wording, this is simply wrong. Yes, the word has multiple meanings, but this is one of them. Actually in ordinary usage, I think it's the most common meaning.

It's certainly possible that in any given case, the meaning could be ambiguous. (This word is hardly unique in that way. Lots of words have multiple definitions that can sometimes result in ambiguity.) If you are talking to a nurse who performs enemas, and who once helped you escape from a burning building, yes, "You evacuated me last month" could be ambiguous.

In practice, though, I think the poster has it backwards. If you use the word "evacuate", most English-speaking people think of fleeing a place of danger or helping other to flee a place of danger, not the emptying of body contents. If anything, you'd more likely need to clarify that you meant the medical procedure and not getting out of someplace.

Answer (score 0):

- Ushering
- Guiding
- Evacuating
- Ejecting

Answer (score 0):

Surely finding the right way to use the verb 'evacuate' can be worked out in context:
"The building was shaking and all the people were evacuated" would be deemed an incorrect use of 'evacuate', whereas "All the people were evacuated *from* the shaking building" would be more acceptable across the range of opinions here. Something to do with transitive and intransitive verbs perhaps........